# My own composer package: automatic dev-master download

Tags: php, github, composer-php, packagist

I'm making my own Composer package for educational purposes. It's just a Laravel extended package with some libraries already installed.

I uploaded to GitHub: [jorgeanzola/laravel](https://github.com/JorgeAnzola/laravel)

I posted it at [Packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/jorgeanzola/laravel)

When I try to run:

```
$ composer create-package jorgeanzola/laravel <path>
```

It gave me this error:

> Could not find package jorgeanzola/laravel with stability stable

In order to make it work, I have to add `=dev-master`, like this:

```
$ composer create-package jorgeanzola/laravel=dev-master
```

It downloads correctly but at the end it gave me this warning:

> Do you want to remove the existing VCS (.git, .svn..) history? [Y,n]?

My question is: How can I set the download process to be more neat? Like, ie: Laravel itself:

```
$ composer create-project laravel/laravel <path>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Release versions of your package, by creating git tags (`git tag`). Then, the latest stable version will be installed when using `composer create-project`.

If you don't want that, then set the stability to dev by doing `composer create-project --stability=dev xxx/yyy`

Comment: Worked as a charm. Thanks! `$ git tag -a v0.1 -m "Release v0.1"`